# LZ4 not compressing strings correctly

Tags: c++, lz4

Recently, I made an attempt to integrate ***loss less data compression*** to my game engine for loading assets; but this simple compression example **does not seem to work correctly**. Any suggestions ? Here is my code :

```
 const char *srcData = "Hi ! This is a really really really long test string !";
 const int dstBufferSize = LZ4_compressBound(sizeof(srcData));
 char *dstData = new char[dstBufferSize];
 int bytesPassed = LZ4_compress_default(srcData, dstData,  
                                       sizeof(srcData), 
                                       dstBufferSize); // compress data
 BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << dstData << std::endl; // print compressed data

 delete[] dstData;
```

This is the output. Obviously, you can see it's wrong (**part of the string is missing**) :

```
[2016-02-24 15:56:47.986366] [0x00000b0c] [info]    @Hi !═══════════════²²²²À▀WÏÇ0
```

**EDIT** 
When decompressing data, only the 'Hi' part is appearing : the rest are random characters/ no characters

**EDIT 2** After Simon's suggestion, I changed the code; but after decompressing the code; i only get Hi ! (nothing after it); Here is the updated code :

```
 const char *srcData = "Hi ! This is a really really really long test string !";
  const int dstBufferSize = LZ4_compressBound(strlen(srcData) + 1);
  char *dstData = new char[dstBufferSize];
  int bytesPassed = LZ4_compress_default(srcData, dstData,  
                                       sizeof(srcData), 
                                       dstBufferSize);
  BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << dstData << std::endl;

  std::ofstream fWriter("test.bin", std::ofstream::binary);
  fWriter << dstData;
  fWriter.close();

  char* decStr = new char[strlen(srcData) + 1];

  LZ4_decompress_fast(dstData, decStr, strlen(srcData) + 1);

  std::cout << decStr << std::endl; // only Hi appearing

  delete[] dstData;
```

Comment: You shouldn't print binary data as text.

Comment: Shouldn't a compressed string not be readable?

Comment: I shouldn't; but when decompressing data, only the 'Hi' part is correct

Comment: The rest is random/ no characters

Comment: @MattMatt Did you try running your code under a debugger?

Comment: Why don't you check the decompressed data?

Comment: I did try running it under a debugger  (VS15)

Comment: The decompressed data is wrong (written into a file using binary format)

Comment: I'll make another edit and post the binaries obtained

Comment: How do you decompress the data? I'm not familiar to the library, but aren't there any functions to finalize the compression?

Comment: @MattMatt And.. Did you step through your code, to see, if all the values of the variables, are what you expect them to be?

Comment: I don't think there are; I just started to use the library, so I'm using documentation

Comment: I don't think that `const int dstBufferSize = LZ4_compressBound(sizeof(srcData));` is correct. `sizeof(srcData)` is most probably 4 or 8.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Kraemer LZ4_compressBound is a LZ4 function that gives the max size of the compressed data, according to the source's size; why not use sizeof(srcData) ? dstBuffer's value is 20, so there should be enough space

Comment: @SimonKraemer That should be an answer.

Comment: Because `sizeof(srcData)` is size of pointer to your string, and is not string length.

Comment: so what should I write instead ? The char count ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `sizeof(srcData)` which will give you the size of the pointer and not of the data it points to.

You should use `strlen(srcData)+1` instead (+1 for the `\0`).

Or use `std::string` and `std::string::size()` (Also with +1 for the null terminator).

Comment: Ok; but now I obtain this:  @Hi !══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²

Comment: after decompressing the string, I obtain : Hi ! without the rest of the string

Comment: You know that you used the wrong size at 2 positions in your code?
`LZ4_compressBound` and `LZ4_compress_default`